# FlowType template not resizing elements

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying out [FlowType](http://simplefocus.com/flowtype/) for text that resizes itself based on the screen width.

I have my own [demo here](http://test.doig.com.au/flowtype/).

Unfortunately the H1 and P elements are not resizing themselves when the viewport width changes.

I can't see what I am doing wrong.

Can you please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing a few things incorrectly on http://test.doig.com.au/flowtype/:

1. flowtype.js (http://test.doig.com.au/flowtype/flowtype.js) file is not a js file. get it from here https://raw.github.com/simplefocus/FlowType.JS/master/flowtype.js.
2. You have included flowtype.js before jQuery. Include flowtype.js **after** jQuery in your document head.

Hopefully that should make it work.

FlowType.JS on GitHub: https://github.com/simplefocus/FlowType.JS

Answer (score 1):

## [Working demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/FXL9k/2/)

```
<script src="flowtype.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You're calling the wrong file (http://test.doig.com.au/flowtype/flowtype.js is not a valid JS file), in the wrong position (before calling jquery http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js).

See your working demo in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FXL9k/2/)